# Verification of the proof $(-x)(-y)=xy$ and a basic question about singleton set

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra

Proof of $$(-x)(-y)=xy$$ Using Field axioms . First two images are the proof by a friend and the third one is my proof.

$\mathbf Objectives-:$ $1$- Is my proof correct and in anyway better than my friend ?(3rd image)

$2$-Do a singleton set has both supremum and infimum ?

$\mathbf Background-$ New to Real analysis and Abstract algebra.

One can probably skip the 1st proof(because it is right) and just examine my proof. I give here the proof by my friend because her proof is quite long compare to mine.

[image][image] [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your proof, on the equality $ -xy + (-x) (- y) = (-x) \big (y + (- y) \big) $ you used that $ (- x) y = -xy $, which is where your friend starts his proof. So, to complete yours, you need to check that too.

To answer the second question, assuming that $F$ is an ordered field, then, of course, for any $x \in F$, $\{x\}$ has an infimum and a supremum, namely
$$\sup \{x\} = \inf \{x\} = x.$$
To see this, observe that from $x \leq x$ we can say that $x$ is an upper and a lower bound for $\{x\}$, and so
$$x \leq \sup\{x\} \leq x \leq \inf\{x\} \leq x$$
where the first and fourth inequalities follows from the definition of supremum and infimum, the second follows because $x$ is an upper bound for $\{x\}$ and $\sup\{x\}$ is the *least* upper bound for $\{x\}$, and the third follows because $x$ is a lower bound for $\{x\}$ and $\inf\{x\}$ is the *greatest* lower bound for $\{x\}$.

Comment: In my proof if I use $(-x)y+(-x)(-y) = (-x)(y+(-y))$ then can I prove it without proving $(-x)y=-xy$ ?

Comment: Well, no. Because the cancellation law that you use in the final step doesn't work unless you prove that $(- x) y = -xy$. You see? Also, I added a better explanation of why $x \leq \sup\{x\} \leq x \leq \inf\{x\} \leq x$.